# Connecting two points in matlab

Tags: matlab, cad

I have two points of which I know the coordinates.I know how to find the length between this two points.In my program I have to connect this points with new "elongated" length and not with actual distance between two points and plot its graph.eg.Suppose Length is 10 between two points but I want to connect them with 18 units .

Comment: I posted an answer that draws a line "pixel by pixel": [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38912084/finding-the-coordinates-on-the-image-knowing-the-center-point-and-slope-of-a-lin/38914305#38914305](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38912084/finding-the-coordinates-on-the-image-knowing-the-center-point-and-slope-of-a-lin/38914305#38914305). You can use a mathematical solution, in case you can't find an existing function that solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question. You want to plot a segment that is collinear to a segment defined by two points, but of a different length. Is this accurate?

I will assume that you want them to have the same midpoint.

```
L = 18;

x0 = 10*(rand(1,2) - 0.5);
y0 = 10*(rand(1,2) - 0.5);

xm = mean(x0);
ym = mean(y0);

m = diff(y0) / diff(x0);
theta = atan(m);

x1 = (L/2) * [cos(theta); -cos(theta)] + xm;
y1 = (L/2) * [sin(theta); -sin(theta)] + ym;

plot(x0, y0, 'r*', x1, y1, '-')
```