# How to stop plotting once line touches perimeter of predefined square?

Tags: matlab, voronoi

I am trying to recreate a Voronoi diagram without actually using the Voronoi function plot. I have a predefined 1x1 square that acts as my "test" area. My code knows where the lines of the diagram intersect the perimeter, but the line doesn't stop there. It keeps going until it reaches a random point.

```
x1 = 6
y1 = x1
x = gallery('uniformdata',[1,x1],0)
y = gallery('uniformdata',[1,y1],1)
sizeofx = size(x,2)
sizeofy = size(y,2)
reshapedx = reshape(x,sizeofx,1)
reshapedy = reshape(y,sizeofy,1)
[vxx,vyy] = voronoi(x,y)

hold on
[v,c] = voronoin([x(:) y(:)]) %intersection point matrix
for i=1:numel(c)
    v(c{i},:)
    ans = ans( ~any( isnan( ans ) | isinf( ans ), 2 ),: )%deletes infs or nans from polygon points
    plot(ans(:,1),ans(:,2),'b-','linewidth',2) %%this code plots the points 
end

%for our test purposes , the voronoi diagram will only be in a 1x1 square.
v(v<0) = inf
v(v>1) = inf
v = v( ~any( isnan( v ) | isinf( v ), 2 ),: ) %deletes the inf or nan

DT = delaunayTriangulation(reshapedx,reshapedy)
[V,R] = voronoiDiagram(DT)
sizeofR = size(R,1)
rectangle('Position',[0,0,1,1])
axis equal

xlimit = [0 1];
ylimit = [0 1];
xbox = xlimit([1 1 2 2 1]);
ybox = ylimit([1 2 2 1 1]);

%finds intersection from diagram to square
for j=1:length(vxx(1,:))
    line([vxx(1,j) vxx(2,j)],[vyy(1,j) vyy(2,j)]);
    [xi, yi, ii] = ...
      polyxpoly([vxx(1,j) vxx(2,j)], [vyy(1,j) vyy(2,j)], xbox, ybox);
        if ~isempty(xi)
                intersectx(j) = xi
                intersecty(j) = yi
                plot(xi,yi,'r*');
                axis equal
        end
 end
```

I want the line to stop plotting once it reaches a perimeter point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the coordinate of line's edge with the intersection point.

Assume line goes from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2).
Check if (x1,y1) is outside the boundaries of the rectangle.
I your case (x1,y1) is outside the boundaries if `(x1<0) || (y1<0) || (x1>1) || (y1>1)`.
In case (x1,y1) is outside, replace (x1,y1) with intersection point (xi,yi).
Note: Replace it only if there is an intersection point.

I ignored the case of two intersection points, because this case never happens in your case (in that case, you need to replace both).

Here is the complete code with the modifications:

```
x1 = 6;
y1 = x1;
x = gallery('uniformdata',[1,x1],0);
y = gallery('uniformdata',[1,y1],1);
sizeofx = size(x,2);
sizeofy = size(y,2);
reshapedx = reshape(x,sizeofx,1);
reshapedy = reshape(y,sizeofy,1);
[vxx,vyy] = voronoi(x,y);

hold on
[v,c] = voronoin([x(:) y(:)]); %intersection point matrix
for i=1:numel(c)
    v(c{i},:);
    ans = ans( ~any( isnan( ans ) | isinf( ans ), 2 ),: );%deletes infs or nans from polygon points
    plot(ans(:,1),ans(:,2),'b-','linewidth',2); %%this code plots the points 
end

%for our test purposes , the voronoi diagram will only be in a 1x1 square.
v(v<0) = inf;
v(v>1) = inf;
v = v( ~any( isnan( v ) | isinf( v ), 2 ),: ); %deletes the inf or nan

DT = delaunayTriangulation(reshapedx,reshapedy);
[V,R] = voronoiDiagram(DT);
sizeofR = size(R,1);
rectangle('Position',[0,0,1,1]);
axis equal

xlimit = [0 1];
ylimit = [0 1];
xbox = xlimit([1 1 2 2 1]);
ybox = ylimit([1 2 2 1 1]);

%Vxx and Vyy are going to be a new set of line coordinates, replacing vxx and vyy.
Vxx = vxx;
Vyy = vyy;

%finds intersection from diagram to square
for j=1:length(vxx(1,:))

    %line([vxx(1,j) vxx(2,j)],[vyy(1,j) vyy(2,j)]);

    [xi, yi, ii] = ...
      polyxpoly([vxx(1,j) vxx(2,j)], [vyy(1,j) vyy(2,j)], xbox, ybox);
        if ~isempty(xi)
                intersectx(j) = xi;
                intersecty(j) = yi;
                plot(xi,yi,'r*', 'MarkerSize', 10);
                axis equal

                %Replace line edges outsize the rectangle with the inersection point.
                %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                x1 = vxx(1,j);
                x2 = vxx(2,j);
                y1 = vyy(1,j);
                y2 = vyy(2,j);
                is_outsize1 = (x1 < 0) || (y1 < 0) || (x1 > 1) || (y1 > 1);
                is_outsize2 = (x2 < 0) || (y2 < 0) || (x2 > 1) || (y2 > 1);

                %Assume rectangle's boundaries are (0,0) to (1,1)
                if is_outsize1
                    %Replace the coordinate [vxx(1,j), vyy(1,j)] with [xi, yi].
                    Vxx(1,j) = xi;
                    Vyy(1,j) = yi;
                end

                if is_outsize2
                    %Replace the coordinate [vxx(2,j), vyy(2,j)] with [xi, yi].
                    Vxx(2,j) = xi;
                    Vyy(2,j) = yi;
                end
                %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        end

    %Plot the line with the replaces coordinates
    line([Vxx(1,j) Vxx(2,j)],[Vyy(1,j) Vyy(2,j)], 'color', 'g', 'LineWidth', 1, 'Marker', '+');
end
```

Result:
[image: Voronoi result]

Original plot:
[image: Voronoi original]

Comment: I like your approach. This was really helpful. Is there any way to literally stop the line from plotting right when it touches the boundaries of the square?

Comment: In order to "literally stop the line from plotting", I suppose you required to implement a customized line drawing function. Draw the line pixel by pixel starting from the point inside the rectangle. For every drawn pixel, check if it steps on the boundaries, and stop drawing if it does. I once tried doing [something close] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38912084/finding-the-coordinates-on-the-image-knowing-the-center-point-and-slope-of-a-lin/38914305#38914305). There must be a better example for drawing a line "pixel by pixel".

Comment: Is it possible to make this code universal for all squares, not just a 1x1? Is it also possible to update the existing vertices array for these shapes with the ones that are intersecting with the square?

Comment: All squares: modify `(x1 < 0) || (y1 < 0) || (x1 > 1) || (y1 > 1)` to the coordinates of the corner of the square. Example: `(x1 < X1) || (y1 < Y1) || (x1 > X2) || (y1 > Y2)`

Comment: "Is it also possible to update the existing vertices array for these shapes with the ones that are intersecting with the square?", I don't understand the sentence. I think `Vxx` and `Vyy` are the vertices array intersecting with the square. So just do: `vxx = Vxx; vyy = Vyy;`, but I am not sure...

Comment: What I meant for the vertices array is that for this code example we used ```[Vxx,Vyy] = voronoi(x,y)```. Are you able to code this with the function ```[[v,c] = voronoin([x(:) y(:)]);``` The voronoin function gives you the vertices of each shape. After this code finds the intersections with the square, it should add it to the coordinate array.

Comment: Sorry... I tried to think of a solution, but I don't think I can implement it correctly.

Comment: I was trying to figure out a cleaver way to code in a way that each intersection point would add itself onto a shape's coordinate array that was closest to that intersection point.